# React Native: pointerEvents = 'none' does not work on a stacked FlatList

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a component that is composed of two child components. The former is the panel with information about the list, and the latter is a FlatList component with the actual contents of the list.

I stacked the components such that the FlatList component is placed on top of the panel component so that when a user scrolls down, the panel is covered by the FlatList, and when the user scrolls up to the beginning of the list, the panel appears again. I also intentionally chose to split the two components rather than incorporating them into a single FlatList to prevent state changes in one component from triggering rerender of the other.

To achieve this, I created a transparent View component in the FlatList component as a header and applied pointerEvents='none' to it so that the panel component behind it is visible and touchable. However, the panel component is not receiving any of the touches.

Here is the simplified code that I wrote:

```
    const List = () => {
    /*
    */
        return (
            <>
            <TopPanel props={props} />
            <PostArray props={props} />
            </>
        );
    };

    const TopPanel = () => {
    /*
    */
        return (
            <View
            style={{
                width: "100%",
                height: 145,
                top: 0,
                position: "absolute",
                zIndex: 1,
            }}
            >
                <PanelComponent />
            </View>
        );
    };

    const PostArray = () => {
    /*
    */

        const ListHeader = () => {
            return (
            <View
                style={{
                height: 145,
                backgroundColor: "transparent",
                width: "100%",
                }}
                pointerEvents="none"
            />
            );
        };

    return (
        <FlatList
            style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%", zIndex: 99 }}
            data={[0]}
            ListHeaderComponent={<ListHeader />}
            renderItem={() => <ModalButtons />}
            ListFooterComponent={
                <View style={{ zIndex: 99, width: "100%" }}>
                <FlatList
                    data={props}
                    renderItem={renderItem}
                    windowSize={15}
                    initialNumToRender={15}
                    maxToRenderPerBatch={15}
                    updateCellsBatchingPeriod={100}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                    getItemLayout={(data, index) => ({
                    length: 120,
                    offset: 120 * index,
                    index,
                    })}
                />
                </View>
            }
            stickyHeaderIndices={[1]}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            />
        );
    };
```

What is possibly wrong here? Any suggestions/ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm dealing with a similar issue. It seems that when ListHeaderComponent is rendered, it is being wrapped in a View. You can illustrate this by also setting ListHeaderComponentStyle={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}. While you can change the style of this invisible wrapper View, I don't yet see how to add a property to it like pointerEvents='box-none'.